# dotted lines in TOC, LOF, LOT as image

Tags: table-of-contents

I am about to submit my dissertation but unluckily I am above the word limit. I counted the words in the PDF created by latex using a commercial software. I also saved the PDF to a word document using adobe acrobat and then used the word count in microsoft word. I realised, that the dots used to fill the gap between, for instance, a table name in the LOT and the page number are counted as words. This sums up to over 3000 extra "words". I was wondering if it is somehow possible to replace those dots with, well, an image of dots or so so that they are not counted as such. I thought of using a line rather than dots but that looks a bit awful...

Any ideas on that??

Comment: Would suppressing the dots be an option? Which document class are you using?

Comment: @Jochen: Do you know whether that's how your university is going to do the word count as well? Maybe it's not a problem to hand it in as it is.

Comment: well, yeah I thought of that option too but does not entirely convince me. I would use it as a last solution before shrinking the text itself even more.. My document class: \documentclass[10pt, DIV=12, a4paper, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}

Comment: well, yeah they say the entire document...it's honestly so ridiculous

Comment: You can reduce the number of dots putting `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{15}\makeatother` in your preamble (adjust the number to your needs).

Comment: @Jochen: It might work if you replace the period with a lowered `\cdot`: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand \dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss \raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\cdot$} \hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother` (at least the word counter at http://felix-cat.com/tools/wordcount/ stops counting them as words, then). Feels horrible to have to do something like that, though.

Comment: haha, yeah you are right. I will try this right now! thanks for this suggestion jake! If that works, would be fantastic

Comment: @Jochen: Take a look at the package »tocstyle«. It is part of »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« and has its own manual which you can access on the command line by typing `texdoc tocstyle`. Use its `\tocstyle{noonewithdot}` to get all ToC entries without dots. Note that you will get a warning about the alpha status of this package. For me it worked so far without problems.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. I tried the above approach by setting the separation between the dots to 1000 rather than 15 which got rid of the dots as well and they are not counted any longer. However, I am curious whether Jake's approach will do it.

Comment: @Jake just tried and did not work but I also just changed the values of .33em and -0.5 to different values and it seems that the code has no effect? It's placed in my preamble before \begin{document}

Comment: @Jochen: Oh yeah, sorry, Koma script doesn't seem to use the `\dotfill` command for generating the dotted line.

Comment: Is there any workaround for that or a similar approach which achieves the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the period with a tiny square `\rule` may work (depending on how the word counting mechanism is implemented):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{\kern \@dotsep pt\hbox{\rule{1pt}{1pt}}\kern \@dotsep pt}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks for this solution. It works when exporting the PDF to word via adobe acrobat. Microsoft word does not recognise it as a word any longer. However, the commercial software still does uh :( I cannot really follow your code but what type/kind of dot is that you are using. Do you think it might work when replacing the dot you are using by a proper image or symbol??

Comment: @Jochen: Hm, wow, this is frustrating! Alright, another try: Using a `\rule` (I've edited the answer).

Comment: I am really sorry but I really appreciate your efforts! I try your new solution now

Comment: @Jochen: I just edited the answer a little bit more, removing the math environment that was put around each dot. Maybe that helps (the spacing is a little bit different now, you might have to adjust the `\@dotsep`)

Comment: @Jochen: By the way, what's the word counting software called?

Comment: hey Jake! that's really a fabulous solution it works with both evaluation methods :) absolutely brilliant. thanks a lot! the commercial software I used is called AnyCount. Sorry for late reply but my computer said goodbye ;) I hope that others who are also struggling with such a problem will stumble across your solution. I am sure they will appreciate it like I do :)

Comment: @Jochen: Glad it helped! Man, that would have been the most annoying reason to have to make changes to the text. Might be worth sending AnyCount a bug report for this.

Comment: Yeah you did indeed :) yes i would since the dots really summed up to about 3200 words. That's quite a lot! You think your first solution should actually have worked? If you supply that to me again in your answer I will send them an email asking whether this might be a bug or not.

Comment: @Jochen: No, the first solution shouldn't have worked, because the `\dotfill` macro isn't actually used for generating the row of dots (that was a wrong assumption on my part). I'm pretty sure that the behaviour of AnyCount is faulty: There's no good reason why a row of periods should count as words (I'm amazed that a software whose only purpose is counting words would have a flaw like that).

Comment: yeah sorry, I actually meant your second solution which worked for microsoft word but not for anycount. But yeah you are right, in both situations the word counters shouldn't have counted the dots as words. that's stupid ;) well, now, I am just glad it's sorted and I can submit next week! Thanks so much again for your assistance. More than appreciated